# How can I modify and view constraints I have already created in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I would like to both see the constraints that I have added to a table and modify them. How can I do this? It is not letting me use `ALTER TABLE user MODIFY CONSTRAINT userCreation;`

Comment: If you read the duplicate link, you will see that you need to first drop/remove the old constraint, then add a new one.  I'm not sure that MySQL has a `MODIFY CONSTRAINT` capability.

Comment: to check all your constrains try `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName;`